# Why does health insurance end at termination day instead of last day of termination month?

Tags: united-states, benefits, insurance

At my company all benefits end at termination day. I thought companies pay health insurance companies for a full month or longer so why does health insurance end at termination day? Do companies pay premiums only for the days employees are employed?

Comment: I think that's up to the company. They don't have to terminate your insurance immediately, they just chose to.

Comment: What country?  My guess is USA but different countries handle insurance differently so you may get different answers.

Comment: There's a difference between "you can only buy this in month-long chunks" and "on a continual basis, you will be billed monthly". I think your question stems from assuming your insurance is the former, while it could be the latter.

Comment: It's very common for insurances to refund the "unused" premium on termination. So it's likely just money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the company.

Most large companies (and quite a few smaller companies) are self-insured.  They hire an insurance company to administer the plan (things like processing claims) and as insurance if there are catastrophic levels of claims but during normal operations the company itself ultimately pays the bill.  In that case, the company has an incentive to terminate benefits immediately following termination in order to avoid paying out any claims you incur for the remainder of the month.  An employer might be kind and cover you through the end of the month anyway but companies don't generally love paying costs for people they've terminated.

If your employer isn't self-insured then, yes, they'd pay the insurance carrier a monthly premium and there would be basically no benefit to having insurance terminate in the middle of the month.  It would be extra work for the employer and the insurance company for exceptionally little potential benefit.  It is unlikely an employer would incur those costs just to spite a terminated employee but weird things do happen.

Comment: Most insurances will refund a pro-rated premium on termination, I don't have lot of experience with health insurance specifically my other insurances all do this.

Comment: @Hilmar - Consumer insurance, sure.  I've not heard of a small group health insurer that would remove a member in the middle of a month and issue a refund to the company.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be a condition imposed by the insurance company.

Health insurance rates depend on what job you do (this also applies to many other types of insurance, such as life assurance and car insurance, but even house insurance may ask about your profession). They also depend on where you're working, and other factors that are job-specific.

If you give up your current job and start work as a shark fisherman or oilworker tomorrow, then your insurance risk has rocketed - especially for your first few weeks or months on the job. Hence it makes sense to only offer insurance when you know what the person is doing.